# Problem with getting the username in Active Dirctory using PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am connecting to an Active Dirctroy server using the following code:

```
$ldapHost = "ldap://XXX.com";
$ldapPort = "389";
$ldapUser ="XXX@XXX.com";
$ldapPswd ="XXX";

$ldapLink =ldap_connect($ldapHost, $ldapPort)
or die("Can't establish LDAP connection");


ldap_bind($ldapLink,$ldapUser,$ldapPswd)
or die("Can't bind to server.");
```

It's working well, but how can I print the username? That is, any time a user visits the page, I want to print the user's name that's stored in Active Directory.

Comment: [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php#26692) is old so the actual AD query syntax hes using may or may not be different now, but it illustrates what you need to do on the PHP side after you bind. You may need to research how to craft create the AD filter/query that is going to give you the specific user you're looking for.

Comment: thank you. Actually I did search but no results that whay i'm asking for help :(

Comment: Are you authneticating the web site user against AD or are you just tryign to get their name display name from AD?

Comment: I just want to display their name from AD for example my name in AD is Smith so I want when I enter the webpage it says (welcome Smith)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`ldap_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) in order to retreive the attributes called `sn` and `givenName`.

You have to search in the `subtree` `from dc=xxxx,d=com` with a LDAP filter like `(userPrincipalName=$ldapUser)`.